# Make a splitter very thin and grab it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, splitter

I want to make a draggle splitter between 2 panels. The following is a working version.

Now, I want to make the width of `handle` as thin as possible (less than `0.1px`?), so there is no way to make the width (**appear**) smaller than `1px`?

Additionally, when the splitter is thin, it is hard to select by the mouse. Is there a way to make a splitter easy to grab?

Taking [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jidoko/6/edit?html,css,js,output) as example, how did they manage to realise the splitters among the panels?

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.drags = function(opt) {
    
    opt = $.extend({
      handle: "",
      cursor: "ew-resize",
      min: 10
    }, opt);

    if (opt.handle === "") {
      var $el = this;
    } else {
      var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }

    var priorCursor = $('body').css('cursor');

    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
      
      priorCursor = $('body').css('cursor');
      $('body').css('cursor', opt.cursor);

      if (opt.handle === "") {
        var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
      } else {
        var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
      }
      
      var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
        drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
        drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
        pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
        pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
      
      var mouseMove = function(e) {        
        
        var prev = $('.draggable').prev();
        var next = $('.draggable').next();

        var total = prev.outerWidth() + next.outerWidth();
        
        var totalPercentage = parseFloat(prev.css('flex')) +  parseFloat(next.css('flex'));

        var offset = prev.offset();
        if(offset){
          var leftPercentage = ((e.pageX - offset.left - drg_w / 2) / total) * totalPercentage;
          var rightPercentage = totalPercentage - leftPercentage;

          if (leftPercentage * 100 < opt.min || rightPercentage * 100 < opt.min) {
            return;
          }

          prev.css('flex', leftPercentage.toString());
          next.css('flex', rightPercentage.toString());
        }
      }
      
      $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parent().on("mousemove", mouseMove).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).off("mousemove", mouseMove).off("mouseup");
            $('body').css('cursor', priorCursor);
            $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
        });
      e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$('.handle').drags();
```

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
.flex-box .col {
  border: 1px solid grey;    
  flex: 0.33;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hide;
}
.handle {
  width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: grey;
  transition: all ease-in 0.1s;
}
.draggable {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Pellentesque ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="handle"></div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Pellentesque ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A pixel is the smallest unit that can be displayed on a screen; how do you expect a browser to render `0.1px`?

Comment: Maybe make part of it not visible with css? That would allow the mouse a larger area to grab but still be visibly smaller.

Comment: @DavidHobs, I think that may be a solution, could you elaborate more?

Comment: .handle{border:1px solid grey; border-right:0px; width:4px;} .col-left{border-right:0px;} .col-right{ border-left:0px; }
This makes the handle have a 1px grey line but 4px of dragable area. And it removes the center borders from each of the columns, assuming you add the col-left and col-right classes. Here's my edits applied: https://jsbin.com/lojugoxonu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: I see your hack... One problem is that the splitter is not centered; there is a shift between the visible border and the mouse...

Comment: Well, my example wasn't supposed to be a final product, it was more of a proof of concept. Naturally you can adjust it to make blank space equal on both sides of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like the handle to appear thinner try applying a negative value to the right "col" e.g. margin-left: -2px; so it overlaps the left "col" border on the left of it. I don't think you can make the width "appear" as 0.1px. Firefox is the only browser that renders such value. (https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/0-1px-borders/)

```
.flex-box .col:last-child {
   margin-left: -2px;
}
```

//raise handle layer to top

```
.handle {
    .....
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

Hope this helps...

***Edit:**

This is the closest I could get to your request:

```
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
.flex-box .col {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex: 0.33;
  padding: 12px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hide;
}
.flex-box .col:last-child {
   margin-left: -6px;
}
.handle {
  width: 5px;
  text-align: center; 
  transition: all ease-in 0.1s;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: visible;  
}
.handle-inner{ 
   width: 5px; 
   height: 100%; 
   position: relative; 
   margin-left: -10px;
} 
.draggable {
  background: grey;  
}
```

Jsbin :
https://jsbin.com/nupefekuhu/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `margin-left` does make it thinner. But I still need to move the mouse very slowly to find the splitter, is there a way to say "once the mouse is <= 5px close to the splitter, we consider it hovers the splitter"?

Comment: I choose to not add `margin-left: -6px` to `.col`, whereas I make `width: 0.1px` for `.handle`. Visibly it is not bad ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qujutih/8/edit?html,css,js,output))... Thank you...